# Q# factorization Method Program

Tags: programming, resource-request, q#

Is there a method to calculate prime factorization in Q# of Visual Studio of Microsoft Quantum Development Kit?

In the Python language, it is the `sympy.factorint` method.

Or else is there any Q# sample program?

It is like [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) calling Q# from C#.

Answer (score 5):

[Integer factorization sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/samples/algorithms/integer-factorization) in the official Quantum Development Kit samples repository implements Shor's algorithm in Q# and shows how to call it from C#.